# How to unshare a file in a folder (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, file-sharing, file-permissions

I have a folder (lets say, "Folder X"), and inside it a file "Y.doc". How can I share the whole folder, except that one file, in Windows XP?

Answer (score 3):

When a user accesses a file via a network share he/she requires both: permissions on the file share and permissions on the file itself.

Therefore if you want to prevent a specific user from accessing a file you can change the ACL of that file and deny all access to that file for that user. The user will be able to see the file-name in the share but it is impossible to read or change the file content.

Warning: Don't deny file access to all users or a group you are member of - otherwise you would also loose read/write access to that file because deny ACL entries have a higher priority that standard grant ACL entries.

Comment: How do I modify the ACL?

Comment: Open the context menu of the file, select _Properties_. In the opened dialog select the security tab and press the Edit button.

Comment: I don't see any security tab in Windows XP

Comment: Then you have only XP Home edition and you are not part of a domain. Hence the solution will not work for you.

Comment: It's Win XP Professional.

Comment: @Inkbug you must disable „simple file sharing” in folder options to get the security tab.

Comment: You can change file permission via command line. `cacls /E /R <The user account> <The protected file>`, eg. `cacls /E /R guest "D:\shared_folder\my-secret-diary.txt"`

Comment: @kinokijuf Sorry for the delay. I just tried it and I have a security tab, but I wasn't able to figure out what to do - if I denied access for "everyone" so then even I couldn't open it (although I still could change the permissions back).

Comment: What do you mean by inheritance? (I don't use WinXP usually)

Answer (score -1):

You could hide the file, and if someone on the network has shared file viewing disabled they won't see it?

Comment: I want the file to be totally inaccessible.

Comment: It might be better to put in a different folder, as far as I'm aware there's no way of changing the sharing to that level of detail. You could try editing the permissions?